# Class Inheritance from ASCX control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a problem on inheriting classes that have ASCX markup pages attached to it. See, i wrote the following ASCX markup and Codebehind:

**ASCX**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="HeaderBlock.ascx.vb" Inherits="CentralWeb.EMP.UI.HeaderBlock" %>
<h1>
    <abbr><%= Me.Label></abbr>
    <span>
        <asp:Button ID="saveandreturnbutton" Text="Salvar e Voltar..." runat="server" CssClass="saveandback" />
        <asp:Button ID="savebutton" Text="Salvar..." runat="server" CssClass="save" />
        <asp:Button ID="return_results" Text="Voltar..." runat="server" CssClass="back" />
    </span>
</h1>
```

**Codebehind**

```
Namespace EMP.UI
    Public Class HeaderBlock
        Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.UserControl
        Protected saveandreturnbutton As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
        Protected savebutton As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
        Protected return_results As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button

        Public Overridable Sub TakeAction(ByVal eventId As Integer)
            'NOTHING, THIS IS THE BASE CLASS
        End Sub

        Private Sub saveandreturn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Global.System.EventArgs) Handles saveandreturnbutton.Click
            Me.TakeAction(3)
        End Sub

        Private Sub savebutton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Global.System.EventArgs) Handles savebutton.Click
            Me.TakeAction(2)
        End Sub

        Private Sub return_results_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Global.System.EventArgs) Handles return_results.Click
            Me.TakeAction(1)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then, my intention is to use this base class (that have a markup), and inherit it to a non-marked up class, and refer it on a page. Like this:

```
Namespace EMP.UI
    Public Class FrontHeader
        Inherits EMP.UI.HeaderBlock

        Public Overrides Sub TakeAction(ByVal I As Integer)
            'CHILD CLASS ACTIONS HERE
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

What's wrong on that test?

**EDITION**

After talking a litle with Tim, i'd like to do somthing like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="HeaderBlock.ascx.vb" Inherits="CentralWeb.EMP.UI.HeaderBlock" %>
<h1>
    <abbr><%= Me.Label></abbr>
    <span>
        <asp:Button ID="saveandreturnbutton" Text="Salvar e Voltar..." runat="server" CssClass="saveandback" />
        <asp:Button ID="savebutton" Text="Salvar..." runat="server" CssClass="save" />
        <asp:Button ID="return_results" Text="Voltar..." runat="server" CssClass="back" />
    </span>
</h1>
<div class="fields">
    PLACE HERE CONTROLS DEPENDING ON THE PAGE WHERE THIS CLASS IS...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: the original question had no `Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl`]*

You need to inherit from `UserControl`:

```
Public Class HeaderBlock
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

 ....
```

But in general i would not inherit a class from a `UserControl` since that is a frontend control which should not contain too much business logic.  If you want to "extend" it you could simply put another `UserControl` in it. The `UserControl` can contain one or multiple other controls, so a modular concept.

Comment: And that would be enought? Not inheriting from UserControl was a type mistake, the original code does. My point is, on the final page, if i register the FrontHeader class, will it load the ASCX from HeaderBlock?

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: have you tried it? In general i would not inherit classes from `UserControls`. The `UserControl` is a frontend class. If you want to "extend" it you could simply put another `UserControl` in it. Then your `UserControl` contains one or multiple other controls.

Comment: Truly, no, i haven't tried. I inherited other controls and worked fine, but the base class was TextBox, Buttons and so on... they don't have ASCX attached, on those i rewrote the render method and it was done, this one on the other hand, i made a base class, with the ASCX and i need to inherit that. My problem is that i'll inherit like 100 classes from it, and i don't want to have an ASCX file for each one.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: why do you need to inherit from it at all? The controller of a `UserControl` is the page(or another control that contains this `UserControl`). So not the `UserControl` itself. Don't add your business logic in a child class, then you can't reuse the `UserControl` for a different purpose which is against its nature. What do you want to do in `TakeAction`? I'm fairly sure that this belongs into the page that holds the `UserControl`.

Comment: That will depend, for example, i'll have 1 page called employees, with many controls for it's field and that FrontHeader that will run 1 other class to do the business, on another page i'll have another class to run another thing and so on...

Comment: it is just the "Header" of the page and its buttons. The final page determinates what funcions will run

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: that doesn't explain why you think that you need to inherit from it. If the page determines that, then it belongs there.

Comment: Could be... on that case i agree. I made that question more theoretically because i have other and bigger controls from what i'd like to inherit too, this one was the simplest.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: even if they are bigger you should not inherit from them. Nest them in each other. The outer `UserControl` controls the inner `UserControl`. That means they communicate via properties, methods and events. The outer control to the inner via properties and methods(f.e. `TakeAction(blah)`) and the inner to the outer [via events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3)(f.e. `ActionTaken`) that the outer control can handle. On that way they can still live  independently and you have maximum control over logic and layout.

Comment: Yes, but how will i nest UserControls inside?

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: just drag&drop them on your ascx like you do on your page.

Comment: Yes, then i'd have an ASCX for each page i build, witch would lead to the same thing...

Comment: Let's me post an answer below with what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: then you have one or multiple ascx in your page, every ascx has none, one or multiple ascx in it which also have none,one or multiple ascx in it and so on. If you want to explain your question further you have to edit your question. Answers are for answers only.

Comment: @SammuelMiranda: maybe you have overlooked in my second last comment that i said `ascx` not `aspx`. By the way, the name `HeaderBlock` leads me to think that you should have a look at `MasterPages`.

Comment: Well, that is an ASCX. i'll place the edited ASCX (i wrote above on the question) on an ASPX page, but the insides of it will be different on each ASPX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73161/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-sammuelmiranda).